# What is the (preferrably one-word) primary term for @XToX annotated fields?

Tags: java, jpa, associations, terminology, relationship

Question pretty much says it all.

You can read "entity association" [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html), but there's "relationship" [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html)

Which term is the primary one? (Sorry, I don't have access to the JPA spec.)

"Entity" basically just designates a reference to a class tagged with @Entity, so the basic question is to choose between association, relationship, or another.

An association of course is the UML term for all kinds of references between "real" classes (entity, composite PK class, enums etc.), that is - as I understand it - not necessarily a reference to one of the Java simple "wrapper" types like Integer, String, Boolean etc. A relationship is the relational term and better represents the fact that every @XToX/@JoinColumn(s) field actually represents a foreign key. This is what I'm looking for.

So, in JPA are we talking about associations? Relationships? Another term? (I tend to prefer "relationship" because of the fact that it represents a foreign key.)

Comment: You do have access to the JPA spec: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html

Comment: I wonder why I believed it's not accessible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the JPA spec the primary term is "relationship". See the JPA 2.0 spec http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html

Thanks to Christoffer Hammarström for posting the link.

Answer (score 1):

Both "association" and "relationship" are used and are fine.

Comment: Which one is the primary one, e.g. as used in the JPA spec?